# "Error 404" when posting SignOutUser to Firebase

Tags: firebase, post, http-status-code-404, gdscript, google-identity-toolkit

I write a code to access Firebase.
I use `HTTPRequest` to login, register, delete account etc.
All work well but one method - `logout = SignOutUser` - always returns with `404 Error`, `unknown URL`.

Links that work with HTTPRequest:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=%s
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=%s
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/deleteAccount?key=%s
```

(with proper `API key` added to the string, of course)

And the one that doesn't work:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signOutUser?key=%s
```

What can be the problem? Can it be fixed?
Is there any other way to logout a user?
I write the code in gdscript, but I tried it via web code too, same result.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am stuck with the very same problem, there is a similar thread that discuss "signOut" functionality. See their accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54262201/2402281
Additionally, I am looking if there is a way to shorten the "ttl" of the token so that the request token gets invalidated but I am not there yet and also not sure if it is really necessary or doable.

Comment: Thank You for the link! I try to solve it in that way, unfortunately I have no "auth" object, but I try to find out how to define one.

Comment: Have a look at the "firebase" package on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/firebase/#authentication :)